# Trouble initiating Tumblr API

Tags: php, api, tumblr

Just downloaded the current "official" Tumblr API from https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php and made a super-minimal test page to check it, after getting all the keys. The keys are correct, and the pathnames are correct:

```
<?php

$consumerKey    = 'xxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxx';
$token          = 'xxx';
$tokenSecret    = 'xxx';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

include('correct_path/API/RequestHandler.php');
include('correct_path/API/RequestException.php');
include('correct_path/API/Client.php');

// Authenticate via OAuth
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $tokenSecret);

echo 'Hello';
```

As soon as it hits the "new Tumblr" line, the script crashes. It will not echo Hello, but if I comment out that line, it will echo Hello. Never reports any errors. This script is so simple that for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. Hopefully it's so simple and obvious that I can't see it. I'm on PHP 5.6. on CentOS. Help?

Comment: Turn on error reporting: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your script..  Also, what do your logs say?  I'm guessing it can't find the Tumbler package due to namespace issues.

Comment: As you can see in the code, error reporting is already on; and nothing shows in the log that I can find.

Comment: To effectively activate error reporting you have to add `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`. In your case, 90% you have a Fatal Error (I suppose that because you don't see “Hello”), that is not visible in HTML page: take a look at your server errors log to see details about error.

Comment: Try the `ini_set("display_errors", 1)` as well just in case.  If it is hitting an error, and error reporting is on, then something should show up.  If that isn't working and you don't have an IDE with debugging features, start peppering `echo`s and `var_dump`s into `correct_path/API/Client.php`.

Comment: Sure enough; it is reporting:
`Fatal error: Class 'Tumblr\API\RequestHandler' not found in correct_path/API/Client.php on line 23`
How could this be failing? It's Tumblr's official API, surely somebody would have caught this if the problem was on the API's end.